# find all subarrays of a given array in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, arraylist

How to find all the subarrays of a given array in the fastest possible way?
for eg:a=[1,2,3,4,5]
The purpose of question is to large array input and find all the possible saubarrays

Comment: Did Google say "zero results found" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

def sub_lists(my_list):
subs = [[]]
for sub in my_list:subs +=  [i + [sub] for i in subs]
return subs

Comment: Lets say the input list is [5,7,1]. We don't get [1,5] subarray in output

Answer (score -1):

Now sure what you meant by sub arrays, but sounds like you want all the permutations of the contents in a given array. Which can be found here:

[How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)